# I'm making differentiating function in OCaml and I have some problems

Tags: list, ocaml, differential-equations

first, this is my code :

```
module Problem1 = struct
  type aexp = 
  | Const of int
  | Var of string
  | Power of string * int
  | Times of aexp list
  | Sum of aexp list

  let diff : aexp * string -> aexp
  = fun (exp, var) ->
        match exp with
        |Const a -> Const 0
        |Var x -> if x = var then Const 1 else Var x
        |Power (s, i) -> 
            if s = var then Times[Const i;Power (s, i - 1)] else Power (s, i)
        |Times l ->
            match l with
                |h::t -> Sum[Times[diff (h, var);t];diff (t, var)]
        |Sum m ->
            match m with
                |h::t -> Sum[diff(h, var); diff(t, var)];; 
end
```

The interpretor says,

```
Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type aexp list
       The constructor Sum does not belong to type list
```

But I intended the symbol m to be an aexp list.
Can't find what is wrong.

Comment: By the way, this is the fifth question you asked on stackoverflow and none of them have an accepted answer which is kind of rude because people do some efforts for you, you could at least thank them by accepting the answer you find appropriate.

Comment: Oh I'm so newbie in stackoverflow and I didn't know how to accept answers. I'm sorry... Thank for your kindness.. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your problem is simple and you would have seen it by using a tool that knows how to indent OCaml code ;-)

Look at how your last lines are indented with an OCaml indenter :

```
    |Times l ->
      match l with
        |h::t -> Sum[Times[diff (h, var);t];diff (t, var)]
        |Sum m ->
          match m with
            |h::t -> Sum[diff(h, var); diff(t, var)];;
```

Yes, that's right, since you created a new pattern matching in `Times l`, `Sum m` is included in it. You should write

```
    |Times l -> begin
      match l with
        |h::t -> Sum[Times[diff (h, var);t];diff (t, var)]
      end
    |Sum m ->
       match m with
         |h::t -> Sum[diff(h, var); diff(t, var)];;
```

And it will work just fine.

By the way, you'll have another problem because you didn't write `let rec diff ...` but `let diff` and you're calling `diff` recursively.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this part looks off: `Times[diff (h, var);t]`. Since `t` is an `aexp list`, you should use the other list constructor, ::, to make it `Times (diff (h, var) :: t).

Answer (score 1):

If you put `match .. with ..` inside a case of another `match .. with`, you need wrap the internal one with `begin` .. `end`:

```
(* I do not check the code is correct *)
let diff : aexp * string -> aexp
  = fun (exp, var) ->
    match exp with
    |Const a -> Const 0
    |Var x -> if x = var then Const 1 else Var x
    |Power (s, i) -> 
        if s = var then Times[Const i;Power (s, i - 1)] else Power (s, i)
    |Times l ->
        begin match l with
        |h::t -> Sum[Times[diff (h, var);t];diff (t, var)]
        end
    |Sum m ->
        match m with
        |h::t -> Sum[diff(h, var); diff(t, var)]
```

Please install a proper auto-indentation tool such as tuareg or ocp-indent, since they can tell the proper program structure.  Hand indentation often fools your eyes.